# Uniformly Integrable Second Moments and Weak Convergence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of Borel probability measures, and let $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of Borel probability measures with finite second moment. Let $\{\mu_n\} \subset \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ have uniformly bounded second moments, and assume $\mu_n\to \mu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ weakly.

Is it true that $\mu \in \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ?

Comment: Is the assumption uniformly integrable in second moment (as in the title) or just  uniformly bounded second moments (as in the statement of the question?) If the former, then the second moment of $\mu_n$ converges to that of $\mu$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

By Skorohod representation theorem there exists random vectors $X_n$ and $X$ such that $\mu_n$ is the distribution of $X_n$,  $\mu$ is the distribution of $X$ and $X_n \to X$ a.s.

Denote by $X_n^{(1)}$ the sequence of first coordinates of vectors $X_n$. We know that $X_n^{(1)} \to X^{(1)}$ a.s., where $X^{(1)}$ is the first coorndite of vectors $X$.

As $X_n$ have uniformly bounded second moments $sup_{n \ge 1} E ||X_n||^2 < \infty$ then $sup_{n \ge 1} E |X_n^{(1)}|^2 < \infty$.

By Fatou's lemma $ E (X^{(1)})^2 = E \underline{lim} (X_n^{(1)})^2 \le \underline{lim} E(X_n^{(1)})^2 < \infty$.

Similarly $ E (X^{(i)})^2 < \infty$ for all $1 \le i \le d$. It follows that the limit of $P_n$ is in $\mathcal{P}_2(R^d)$, q.e.d.

*Addition*

By De la Vallée-Poussin criterion for Uniform Integrability  $\{X_n^{(1)} \}_{n\ge 1}^{\infty}$ is a uniformly integrable class of r.v. Hence $X^{(1)} \in L_1$ and $EX_n^{(1)} \to EX^{(1)}$. But $EX_n^2$ doesn't converges to $EX^2$ in general case.

**Example**. Consider $X_n \sim \sqrt{n} Bern(\frac{1}n)$, then $X_n \to 0$. Thus $P_n, P \in \mathcal{P}_2(R^d)$, $EX_n^2 \to 1 \ne 0 = EX^2 $.