# Weak convergence of probability measures with fixed second moments

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Consider Borel probability measures $\mu_n, \mu$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly (test functions are continuous and bounded);
2. $E_{X \sim \mu_n}[X] = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$;
3. $E_{X \sim \mu_n}[X^2] = 1$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Can we conclude that (i) $E_{X \sim \mu}[X] = 0$ or (ii) $E_{X \sim \mu}[X^2] = 1$?

---

Famously, $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly does not imply convergence in first moments. The typical example is $\mu_n := (1-n^{-1})\delta_0 + n^{-1} \delta_n$, so that $\mu_n \to \delta_0$ while $E_{X \sim \mu_n}[X]=1$ and $E_{X \sim \delta_0}[X] = 0$. This isn't a counterexample for our purposes, however, because $E_{X \sim \mu_n}[X^2] = n$.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing the question out, I ended up working out the answer.

For question (i), the answer is yes. This is a consequence of uniform integrability. Since

$$
\sup_n E_{X \sim \mu_n}[X^2] = 1 < +\infty
$$

we obtain $\sup_n E_{X \sim \mu_n}[|X|] < +\infty$ and consequently $E_{X \sim \mu}[X] = 0$; see, e.g., Theorem 3.5 and equation (3.18) in Billingsley, *Convergence of Probability Measures* (1999) for the details.

For question (ii), the answer is no. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3964686/224759) gives an example which can be reworked to fit my question. Taking

$$
X_n = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{w.p. } 1-n^{-1} \\\\
\sqrt{n} & \text{w.p. } n^{-1}
\end{cases}
$$

we see that $E[X_n] = n^{-1/2}$ and $E[X_n^2] = 1$, while $X_n \to 0$ in distribution. Therefore, the centered sequence $Y_n := X_n - n^{-1/2}$ has $E[Y_n] = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var} (Y_n) = 1$, but converges to $0$ almost surely. Formally, $Y_n \sim \mu_n$, where

$$
\mu_n := (1-n^{-1}) \delta_{-n^{-1/2}} + n^{-1} \delta_{n^{1/2} - n^{-1/2}}
$$

has $\mu_n \to \delta_0$ weakly but fails to converge in second moments.

---

I had a hard time understanding this sequence, so I [made it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/skgiictndf).